# How do I run a 5-way ANOVA in R, but factors A and B are nested within random C, factor D is random, and data is unbalanced?

Tags: r, anova, interaction, random-effects-model, nested-data

As far as I can tell it's

```
aov(Y ~ A*B*E + Error((C/(A*B))*D), data=d)
```

But I'm not sure and e.g. I can't tell the difference between that and

```
aov(Y ~ A*B*E + Error((C/(A*B))+D), data=d)
```

**Update**: when I run

```
AnovaModel.1 <- aov(Y ~ A*B*E + Error((C/(A*B))*D), data=d)
Anova(AnovaModel.1,type=3)
```

or

```
AnovaModel.1 <- aov(Y ~ A*B*E + Error((C/(A*B))*D), data=d)
Anova(AnovaModel.1)
```

I get an error message:

```
cannot coerce class ""function"" to a data.frame
```

For the **reproducible example** I invented the data. I opened the library Rcmdr but I didn't use its interface for the reproducible example. I translated a R message but everything else should be straightforward. Reproducible example: http://pastebin.com/9xEvZA8f

Comment: Can you provide a [reproducible example](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Reproducibility.html) and clearly state what you want, what you did and what the problem is. This will help you to get an answer to your question.

Comment: Done! I copied the example in Pastebin. I checked it and it runs. I put all the R output I get as comments in the reproducible example.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error by pasting your code into my R console. I get a different error message `Error in vcov.default(mod) : 
  there is no vcov() method for models of class aovlist, listof`. Also this model is very complex and the reason why you get the other error `Error() model is singular` is probably because you don't have enough degrees of freedom to fit the model as it is specified now. Furthermore, why are you not using a mixed effects model if you have random variables?